# What should I do to verify an OAuth signature in PHP with PECL OAuthProvider?

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-provider

I'm trying to verify an OAuth signature in PHP with PECL OAuthProvider. But almost its functions is not documented.
ex) http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.setparam.php

What should I do?
Is there unofficial document or sample code for PECL OAuthProvider?

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth for everything is similar, but not the same. You should look up the OAuth instructions from wherever you are getting the tokens and what not from (i.e. if you're checking Gmail through your app, you should check the Google OAuth)

Comment: I'm trying to make mixi App. (mixi is Japanese SNS) But documents by mixi, Inc. are too simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to do the same for a while now and have found the lack of documentation very frustrating.

These documents have helped me a lot and may be of some use to you as well.

https://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/php-oauth-provider-request-tokens

I believe what you are looking for is [OAuthProvider::checkOAuthRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/oauthprovider.checkoauthrequest.php)

Those and constantly looking through http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/ to gain more insight on OAuth.

Hope this helps.